# How to use SLIME indentation with editorconfig in emacs

Tags: emacs, editor, common-lisp, indentation, slime

I use [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) with the emacs plugin.

I like it, especially since it can sync my preferences across editors, and allow project specific settings. But when I edit common lisp files in emacs the editorconfig seems to mess up SLIME's intelligent lisp-specific indentation. i.e. it always indents the same amount instead of using the appropriate indentation or alignment for the current form.

Is there any way to specify that I would prefer to use the SLIME indentation over the editorconfig indentation?

Also, does anyone know how editorconfig interacts with smart-tabs?

Comment: This sounds like an overlookekd feature.  Could you file a bug on the issue tracker? https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues .  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in editorconfig for emacs. It is now fixed.

In order for it to work you should have something like the following in your .editorconfig file:

```
[*.{lisp,asd,el}]
indent_style = space
indent_size = none
tab_width = none
```